# Type mutations work strange in python, why?

Tags: python, mutation

I need to make a simple check for right variable types of my input vars. So I made such function:

```
def is_good_value(some_value, value_type="numeric"):
        """Check if value is of right type"""

        allowed_types = {
            "numeric" : [float, int],
            "string"  : [str],
            "file"    : [os.path.isfile]
        }

        for each_type in allowed_types[value_type]:
            try:
                each_type(some_value)
            except: exit(print(f"Wrong type: {some_value}, should be {allowed_types[value_type]}"))
```

If I try to check:

```
is_good_value("1")
```

I get the exception. Obviosly, it's because I pass the string "1".

But if I make `int("1")` or `float("1")` mutation everything's fine as this value is convertible to these types.

**How can I modify my def to get the same result as in simple mutation operations?**

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you're trying to.do here. Do you want to know if a given string can be converted to a number or not?

Comment: What you describe is not what I'm seeing from this code. I think it needs more basic debugging. It's just falling through and returning None because you don't have a return statement.

Comment: Also, I guess that you are okay with never detecting, say, `'1'` as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `isinstance` (and `isfile` for that file case)...

```
allowed_types = {
    "numeric": lambda v: isinstance(v, (float, int)) and not isinstance(v, bool),
    "string": lambda v: isinstance(v, str),
    "file": os.path.isfile,
}
def is_good_value(some_value, value_type="numeric"):
    return allowed_types[value_type](some_value)
```

Comment: Not sur to get your point. If `v` is `str(1)` then `isinstance(v, (int,))` wont return True.

Comment: Well, to be fair, OP's goal is not very clear either :)

Comment: You are right...